# threejs : trying to pass objloader to a var

Tags: svg, three.js, resize, gsap

I'm trying to pass the result of the objLoader command to a var to use it in an animation. So when I put the console.log inside the objLoader function I get the object. But when I put the console.log outside the function I get undefined.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {height: 100%}
        body {margin: 0}
        #cnv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="cnv">
    </canvas>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/three@0.128.0/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
            sun = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1),
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, 1, 0.1, 10),
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:cnv}),
            boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(.5, .5, .5),
            mtrlStdr = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial(),
            box0 = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, mtrlStdr),
            minLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(),
            minObj,
            canvasResize = function () {
                var canvas = renderer.domElement,
                width = canvas.clientWidth,
                height = canvas.clientHeight;
                if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
                    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
                    camera.aspect = width / height;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                }
            };
            sun.position.set(-5, 10, 6);
            sun.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(sun,sun.target,box0,camera);
            minLoader.load('models/min.obj', function (obj) {
                scene.add(obj);
                minObj=obj;
            console.log(minObj);
            });
            camera.position.z = 6;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            function animate(time) {
                time *= 0.001;
                box0.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
                box0.rotation.y = time * 1;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            window.addEventListener('load', canvasResize, false);
            window.addEventListener('resize', canvasResize, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me?

the obj file is at : https://banner-testing.neocities.org/models/min.obj

Cheers

Michael

so after Mugen's answer I changed the end of my code a bit and now it works. Woooohooo! Thx Mugen.

Here's the code (only the bits I changed)

```html
function loadObjs () {
                minLoader.load(
                    'models/min.obj',
                    function (obj) {
                        scene.add(obj);
                        minObj=obj;
                        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    }
                );
            };
            function animate(time) {
                time *= 0.001;
                minObj.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
                minObj.rotation.y = time * 1;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            };
            function winit () {
                canvasResize();
                loadObjs ();
            };
            window.addEventListener('load', winit, false);
            window.addEventListener('resize', canvasResize, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I put the console.log outside the function I get undefined.

That happens because the OBJ asset is loaded asynchronously. That means if you access `minObj` before the loading process has been finished, runtime errors will occur since the variable is still `undefined`.

One simple solution is to implement a check before accessing `minObj`:

```js
if ( minObj !== undefined ) console.log( minObj );
```

However, it's better if you start your animation in the `onLoad()` callback so you have the guarantee that `minObj` has a valid value.